# Powershell remotely execute commands

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, remote-access

I am having an issue trying to execute the command remotely. First, the command is trying to copy an executable to the remote system and I think that's where my issue is because you can't access \hostname\C$\Windows\Temp straight, you must connect to C$ first then go to C:\Windows\Temp

That being said, I tried that as well (`$Dest = "C$"`), and still not working

FYI: The folder might or might not exist in the client

```
$SetupFolder = "C$\Windows\Temp\Logs"

$Path = "C:\Windows\Temp\Logs\Install.exe"

$Dest = "C$"

# Remote run the install for each system

foreach ($System in $SystemList) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $System -quiet) { 
        Copy-item $Package -Destination \\$System\$SetupFolder -recurse -Force
        if (Test-Path - Path $Path) {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $System -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe $Path /S} -credential $Credentials

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Installation Successful on $System"
        }

    } else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$System is not online, Install failed"
    }

}
```

Comment: Try it using `cmd /c $Path`

Comment: And yes, you should be able to simply invoke a command on the remote host without having to connect to the Administrative share first. If you're concerned about that, you can also invoke-command against a pssession

Comment: I am sorry but I am bit confused, use cmd c $Path where?

Comment: Sorry bout that, in your execution of `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $System -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "$Path"} -credential $Credentials
`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enter-PSSession` if you cannot use `Invoke-Command`, this starts an interactive session with a remote computer, you will need to have permissions on the remote computer first to connect,

More information in the PowerShell documentation,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1